# VBA Word make every 3 words' bold in a selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

So I have been trying to make every 3 words in a word docuemnt bold in a specific selection or if there is nothing selected every 3 words in the whole document. I tried different approaches but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say "What have you tried so far?" and "Lets see your code.", but I haven't really coded in Word so thought I'd give it a go....

This seems to do the trick, although there may be a much better way to code it:

```
Public Sub BoldText()

    Dim wrd As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim doc As Variant

    If Selection.Start = Selection.End Then
        Set doc = ThisDocument
    Else
        Set doc = Selection
    End If

    x = 0
    For Each wrd In doc.Words
        x = x + 1
        If x Mod 3 = 0 Then
            wrd.Bold = True
        End If
    Next wrd

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for trying VBA with Word. I never even considered it. I automatically read this as if it was an excel question.

Comment: That worked, I just had to make so that it doesn't make commas and full stops for actual words, but you helped me a lot.